# Is it safe removing block-inner clearfix classes from block templates?

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

Is it safe to remove block-inner clearfix templates from block? I use mainly context module which works with blocks. Looking at html there is too much wrappers involved. Thank you.

Comment: Classes are just a stylesheet convenience. If your stylesheet is not referencing the class, then it is probably safe to remove them. Try it out and see. If you site is adversely affected, put them back.

Comment: I use omega theme, clearfix rule contains clear:both and obviously is for removing any floats. I wanted to know if it is neccessarry for admin theme or so. Thank you

Comment: Only way to tell is to try it and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove them, but they are there so that you can properly float elements within your content. That will depend on the modules you use (whether they include clearfix), and your own CSS.

Not sure about whether Admin requires it. In my case, I use an admin theme for all editing, precisely to avoid such complications.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the template that includes that corresponding block. For example, I wanted to remove a clearfix in my branding region. I copied region-branding.tpl.php from the omega directory to my theme's templates directory. I then edited the file and removed the clearfix.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing it is better to override them so that if you need to have them in case of any problem, you should have access to them. For exammple you can override .form-item, .form-text, .clearfix etc. etc.   in your CSS.